# Ошибка "PHP notice Undefined: index: HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET"

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, перенес не мной написанный сайт на другой хостинг и столкнулся с такой ошибкой: `PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET`. На прошлом хостинге было PHP v5.2. На новом PHP v5.6. Может быть в этом дело?

Строка с ошибкой:

```
$id_session = "C".$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего был настроен другой уровень `error_reporting` и в нём игнорировались `NOTICE`, проверьте на хостинге `php.ini` файл или настройки `php.ini` в админке хостинга и замените на следующие:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

Answer (score 0):

Заголовки `HTTP_*` шлет клиент. Они могут отсутствовать. Перед их использованием проверяйте наличие через

```
isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])
isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET'])
```

а если вы еще их содержимое пишите в БД, то **позаботьтесь об исключении SQL-инъекции**.